# need a linq to sql statement to join or default

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq

I have a Prescription table. Prescriptions are related to a Clinic table and a Doctor table.
I also have two relations tables, UserToClinic and UserToPrescribers
Every user is in UserToClinic one or more times. A user is only in UserToPrescribers if the user is restricted to seeing only those Doctors.
If a user is not in UserToPrescribers they should be able to see all Doctors for the Clinics they can see.
I could look for the user in the UserToPrescribers then branch to a different linq query but I am going to have to do this a lot and that will get ugly.

```
var UserPrescribers = from up in c.UserToPrescribers
    where up.UserName == username
    select up;

if (UserPrescribers.Count() == 0)
{
    var result = (from d in c.Drugs
        join s in c.RXes on d.NDC equals s.NDC
        where s.ClinicId == clinicId

        select new Drug
        {
            Name = d.Name,
            NDC = d.NDC
        }).Distinct().OrderBy(m => m.Name).ToList();

    return result;
}
else
{
    var result = (from d in c.Drugs
        join s in c.RXes on d.NDC equals s.NDC
        join p in c.Prescribers on s.PrescriberNPI equals p.NPI
        join up in c.UserToPrescribers on p.NPI equals up.PrescriberNPI
        where s.ClinicId == clinicId && up.UserName == username

        select new Drug
        {
            Name = d.Name,
            NDC = d.NDC
        }).Distinct().OrderBy(m => m.Name).ToList();

    return result;
}
```

Comment: What is your question? Please read this sscce.org

Comment: @reggaeguitar I read it as, "I want to get rid of the first query where I check to see if the user has any prescribers, and also get rid of the if/else statements, by modifying my linq query to handle both cases where the user DOES have some Prescribers and DOES NOT have any Prescribers"

Comment: Yes Rufus L, that is what I meant. I want to eliminate the first query and the if/else statement in the second. 
I want a Linq to sql query to show me all the drugs being prescribed for this clinic unless the user is restricted to a set of prescribers then only show me the ones that those prescribers wrote.
Thanks for looking.